# All build definition for a repository

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to find all build definitions on Azure DevOps for a repository? I need to move a repo to another project and need to make sure I will change the repo path on all build definition.

Comment: The builds are YAML builds or the old classic editor builds?

Comment: we have both kinds of build, mostly old classic editor builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All build definition for a repository

You can use this [**Rest API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to filter all builds which source repository is what you concerned.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/definitions?repositoryId={repos id}&repositoryType=TfsGit&api-version=5.1
```

Just specify the `repos id` and the `repos type`, then it could filter the satisfied builds.

To get the `repository id`, just use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

---

I wrote a simple sample can for you check:

```
$token = "{PAT token}"

$url ="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/definitions?repositoryId={repos id}&repositoryType=TfsGit&api-version=5.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

Write-Host "results = $($response.value._links.web.href | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Since your next step is change the repo path of these satisfied build definition, I think the best and quick way is let you directly know these Builds URL.

At the last line of my script, I `write-host` these **Builds link**. After get these links from above script, you can directly put them into the browser and go the corresponding pipeline location. This can help you reduce the time of pipeline found.

[image]

[image]